# How to fix "' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>?"

Tags: dart, flutter

How are you. Flutter code is map line show errors. This line is. Thank you for time. I dont understand.

It's error :

```
flutter: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>?

  String carModel;
  String carColor;

Map carData={
'carModel':this.carModel,
'carColor':this.carColor
};



Future<void> addData(carData) async {
    if (isLoggedIn()) {
      Firestore.instance.collection('testcrud').add(carData).catchError((e)
      {
        print(e);
      });
    }  else {
      print('Not login');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
Map carData={
'carModel':this.carModel,
'carColor':this.carColor
};
```

to

```
Map<String,dynamic>  carData={
'carModel':this.carModel,
'carColor':this.carColor
};
```